# Get different colors in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a plot that looks like this picture. Anyone know what to change on my code. I am checking the return of 2 different stocks, and then plotting a normal distribution curv.

[image: normal distribution of a stock]

```
# Installer og last inn nødvendige pakker
install.packages("tidyquant")
install.packages("GauPro")
install.packages("kernlab")
library(tidyquant)
library(GauPro)
library(kernlab)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

# Hent historiske aksjedata for Equinor og finner ut av avkastning 1 og 3mnd etter prisen stiger over 50SMA
eqnr <- tq_get("EQNR.OL", from = "2018-01-01", to = "2022-01-01") %>%
  tq_mutate(select = close,
            mutate_fun = SMA,
            n = 50, col_rename = "sma") %>% 
  mutate(cross = if_else(close > sma, 1, 0), 
         first_cross = cross - lag(cross),
         price_1m = lead(close, 20), 
         price_3m = lead(close, 60)) %>% 
  filter(first_cross == 1) %>% 
  mutate(across(contains("price"), ~ round((.x / close - 1) *100, 2), .names = "{.col}_change"))

# Hent historiske aksjedata for Aker BP og finner ut av avkastning 1 og 3mnd etter prisen stiger over 50SMA
akrbp <- tq_get("AKRBP.OL", from = "2018-01-01", to = "2022-01-01") %>%
  tq_mutate(select = close,
            mutate_fun = SMA,
            n = 50, col_rename = "sma") %>% 
  mutate(cross = if_else(close > sma, 1, 0), 
         first_cross = cross - lag(cross),
         price_1m = lead(close, 20), 
         price_3m = lead(close, 60)) %>% 
  filter(first_cross == 1) %>% 
  mutate(across(contains("price"), ~ round((.x / close - 1) *100, 2), .names = "{.col}_change"))

# Kombinerer alle data for olje og energi aksjer til en data frame
Olje_Energi <- bind_rows(eqnr, akrbp)

# Definer området for x-aksen basert på standardavvik og gjennomsnitt
GJ_snitt <- mean(Olje_Energi$price_1m_change, na.rm = TRUE)
Standardavvik <- sd(Olje_Energi$price_1m_change, na.rm = TRUE)
x_verdier <- seq(-3*Standardavvik + GJ_snitt, 3*Standardavvik + GJ_snitt, length.out = 50)

# Beregne sannsynlighetenstettheten for disse avkastningene
normalfordeling <- dnorm(x_verdier, mean = GJ_snitt, sd = Standardavvik)

# Rund av tallene til t0 desimaler
x_verdier_avrundet <- round(x_verdier, 2)

df <- data.frame(x_verdier_avrundet, normalfordeling)

# Lag en ny kolonne i data frame som angir hvilket standardavvik hver avrundet x-verdi tilhører
df$Sigma <- cut(df$x_verdier_avrundet, breaks = seq(-3 * Standardavvik + GJ_snitt, 3 * Standardavvik + GJ_snitt, by = Standardavvik),
                labels = c("-3σ", "-2σ", "-σ", "σ", "2σ", "3σ"))

# Lag et barplot med forskjellige farger for hver standardavvik
ggplot(df, aes(x = x_verdier_avrundet, y = normalfordeling, fill = Sigma)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("-3&sigma;" = "purple", "-2&sigma;" = "blue", "-&sigma;" = "green", "&sigma;" = "green", "2&sigma;" = "blue", "3&sigma;" = "purple")) +
  labs(title = "Fordeling av avkastning basert p&aring; standardavvik",
       x = "Avkastning", y = "Sannsynlighetstetthet") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  annotate("text", x = GJ_snitt, y = max(df$normalfordeling), label = "Gjennomsnitt", vjust = -0.5, hjust = 0.5)
```

i get the same color on every bar of the plot. i also want to add a legend that tells the probablility of each color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the trick is to use `geom_col` after pre-counting the bar heights. I'll demo with fake data:

```r
set.seed(42)
dat <- data.frame(val = rnorm(1000))
head(dat)
#          val
# 1  1.3709584
# 2 -0.5646982
# 3  0.3631284
# 4  0.6328626
# 5  0.4042683
# 6 -0.1061245
```

Code to count and plot.

```r
library(dplyr)
dat |>
  mutate(
    bin1 = cut(val, c(-Inf, seq(-3, 3, by = 0.25), Inf)),
    bin2 = cut(val, c(-Inf, seq(-3, 3, by = 2), Inf))
  ) |>
  summarize(.by = c(bin1, bin2), n = n())  |>
  ggplot(aes(bin1, n)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = bin2))
```

[image: ggplot barplot with band-colored bars]

(The use of `.by=` requires `dplyr_1.1.0` or newer; if you have an older version, change from `mutate(.by=c(..), stuff)` to `group_by(..) |> mutate(stuff) |> ungroup()`.)

The notion here is that `bin1` is for segmenting the data into vertical columns/bars (with height `n`), and `bin2` is used to group these bars into color-categories.